# Designing A Website With A Very Close Look And Feel To A Famoous One

Tags: look-and-feel

First of all I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. But if it's not please note me to delete the question.

Taking a short look on the web you'll find many websites with the same look and feel of the more famous ones. As an example you'll find many websites with the exact design that Groupon website has.

Is it legally permitted? Can it cause the website owners face prosecution? If so, why are so many similar websites on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact reproductions are protected by copyright. Approximations are not.